# How to validate one input field + search-button with Formik in React?

Tags: reactjs, validation, search, formik

I am trying to validate input using Formik with one single input field that is connected to a search button. This is what I want to achieve:

- I want to accept only numbers
- If the user enters alphabetic characters, I want to show a div with a error message.

My question is:

What's the best approach when instead of a submit button I have a SEARCH button?

All the solutions I find so far are with several input fields with a submit button, either like this one:

https://formik.org/docs/api/errormessage

```
 Or like this one:
```

```
 // Synchronous validation
 const validate = (values, props /* only available when using withFormik */) => {
   const errors = {};
 
   if (!values.email) {
     errors.email = 'Required';
   } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
     errors.email = 'Invalid email address';
   }
 
   //...
 
   return errors;
 };
```

My code so far:

```
<FlexItem flex={1.5}>
                        <FormikInput
                            id={`reportName`}
                            name={`reportName`}
                            label={'Invoice number'}
                            
                            placeholder={'Search for an existing invoice number'}
                            onChange={e => {
                                setInput(e.target.value);
                            }}
                            value={input}
                            type={'number'} //?
                        />
                    </FlexItem>
                    <FlexItem className="flex-toolbar-button">
                        <StyledToolbarButton
                            size="normal"
                            buttonStyling="primary"
                            onClick={() => {
                                setSegmentId(segmentInput);
                                setInvoiceId(input);
                            }}
                            disabled={!segmentInput || !input}
                        >
                            Search
                        </StyledToolbarButton>
                    </FlexItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this function will prevent the user from typing in the input if he types anything else than a number:

```
 const handlePreventNonNumericOnKeyPress = e => {
    //on keypress prevent entering nonnumeric values
    //if key code is not between key codes of numeric values from 0 to 9, prevent the action
    if (!(e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

also you should add the `onKeyPress` (or onKeyDown, not sure for Formik) handler on your input, where you call this function, I guess you need it here:

```
<FormikInput
                            id={`reportName`}
                            name={`reportName`}
                            label={'Invoice number'}
                            placeholder={'Search for an existing invoice number'}
                           onKeyPress={handlePreventNonNumericOnKeyPress}        
                          onChange={e => {
                                setInput(e.target.value);
                            }}
                            value={input}
                            type={'number'} 
                        />
```

Comment: It is not really what I want to achieve. I couldn't test your solution cause I got property "onKeypress does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes & props & RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>." What I want to achieve is to throw an error message IF the user enters a string. The search button is disabled by default but when the user enters a number, and ONLY then, the search button is enabled.